# aType does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, types

I'm getting into inheritance but i'm getting stuck with this weird error. What am i doing wrong?

I think the code will be pretty straight forward on what im trying to achieve. The goal is to create multiple subclasses which will identify a couple of different Olympic Games attendees in different categories. The aType variable wille therefore be constant inside each of the different subclasses. But i still want to be able to use the printAttributes function from the baseclass.

```
class olympicAttender{

public:
    string aName;
    int aAge;
    string aGender;
    string aType;

    void speak(){
        cout << aName <<" speaks!" << endl;
    }

    void printAttributes(){
    cout << "Name: " << aName << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << aAge << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << aGender << endl;
    cout << "Type: " << aType << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    }
};

class sprinter : public olympicAttender{

    public:
        aType = "Sprinter";
        void run(){
            cout << aName <<" runs!" << endl;
        }
};

int main(){

sprinter Sprinter1;
Sprinter1.aAge = 31;
Sprinter1.aGender = "Male";
Sprinter1.aName = "Usain Bolt";

Sprinter1.printAttributes();

}
```

Comment: Forgot to copy in the function call in the bottom when i wrote the post, sorry.
Edited.

Comment: `aType = "Sprinter";` Did you intend to put this inside a constructor (hint, hint)? You cannot have any code outside of a function.

Comment: I thought about putting it all inside a constructor(name, gender, age and type) but i couldn't get it to work. Having trouble with the syntax :(

Comment: Finally got it to work with constructors. Thanks for the advice, it's much simpler now.